# How to open Microsoft store and direct to the app if the app is not installed c# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a link, for example, myapp:/offers I need to open my app if this link is clicked.
By using the URI scheme it is working fine. What I need is when the link is clicked it should direct to the app in Microsoft store if the app is not installed.

is there anyway?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I tried Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(). This is useful only to open from the code

Comment: there is also URI named ms-windows-store ... check it out

Comment: you meant this ms-windows-store://pdp/?productid=, from where should I call this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that you have an UWP app which has a custom URI scheme name 'myapp', then now, you're developing an other UWP app to detect if it's installed. If it's installed, you could active the app by clicking the 'myapp:///' link. If it's not installed, you want to directly open the Microsoft Store to show the app's details page.

If so, you could call [Launcher.QueryUriSupportAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.queryurisupportasync) method to see if the app is installed. If it's not installed, you could [launch the Microsoft Store app with the specific URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-store-app) to show your app's details page in Microsoft Store.

If your question just is when the users input the 'myapp:///' URI in Edge browser, if your app is not installed, you want it directly to open Microsoft Store and show the details page. I could tell you that it's impossible. It's controlled by system level. If the 'myapp:///' URI is not registered, you input it in browser, system will popup a prompt [Looking for an app in Microsoft Store](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoI4pKdRYn8KnG_EPB-ym9n9ibXq), then, you could select it and click **OK** button, system will open the Microsoft Store and search the 'myapp'.

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ms-windows-store://pdp/?productid=blah-blah");
```

This piece of code opens URL in default browser for the selected protocol, so it might work for you.

Comment: UWP does not contain a definition for System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(), and I need to open the store if app is not installed. So this won't work if the app is not opened.